# Get the Session ID of a SQL Server Job Submitted from .net

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net

I'd like to add the facility to kill a SQL Server job from a .NET application. The job would be some sort of complex insert or update statement and the way I am doing it, it will run in the background. Once submitted I'd like the facility to kill it in case it's using up too much resource\taking too long etc. So my idea is just to kill the job using the SQL Server Session id, but how do I get this and can I get this at submission time?

Comment: do in transaction and rollback it for your case

Comment: Not a great idea.  Rather set command timeout according to your needs.  (Even if you could find an easy way, would your application always be running with the permissions needed to kill DB jobs?)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The problem is users will sometimes accidently put in large SQL Job then realise their mistake. They don't write the SQL the application generates it from the tests they put in. An SQL Agent stored procedure running in the background would kill the job so privilege won't be an issue.